# Is it necessary to use “start_activity” with Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am using Python 3.7 with appium. After I defined my desired capabilities, I noticed the application is open when I call:

`driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)`

and then y automation test start without issues.

So I was wondering why to use:

```
driver.start_activity("com.app.android", "com.app.mainactivity.MainActivity")
```

?

Because when I write the 2 lines:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps) 
driver.start_activity("com.instagram.android", "com.instagram.mainactivity.MainActivity")
```

I can see Appium launching 2 times the app. So I make the conclusion that it is useless to write a line of code with "start_activity".

Can someone explain me the difference and in which scenario I should use "start_activity" as the declaration of driver with the line:

`driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)`

is enough to start the application and run the test.

Thanks for helping me to understand better appium.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `driver.start_activity` unless you want to switch from the default one you gave in capabilities.

When you start the new session you already providing enough information (package, starting activity) for Appium to launch your application.

If you wonder about the use case for `start_activity`:

- between the tests to reset the app state
- quickly starting the test with custom App state rather than navigating through the app.